# Which map is the best for farming Foxfire Clusters?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm interested in farming Foxfire Clusters to make a Mawdrey backpiece. Which map(s) is/are the best for farming Foxfire Clusters? I'd like to be able to get at least 4 per day to keep up with the daily food crafting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I know of, is [Malchor's Leap](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Malchor%27s_Leap), at the Waypoint by [Pagga's Post](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pagga%27s_Post).

If you head west, there is a cluster of Cypress Saplings as show below:

[image]

I normally head north of the waypoint, then loop south west to the cluster of trees and make a quick sweep of all the trees in the area. I normally have 2 chars camped down there and make a sweep or two every session. Depending on how long you are willing to spend down there, depends how far you wander, and how many trees you find, sometimes I just follow trees on the map for a while. Or you can just camp by the tree cluster :)

Answer (score 2):

There's another simmilar cluster in the Straits of Devastation. Across the bridge from the Waywarde Way Waypoint (http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Waywarde_Way).